# How is the equation of motion for a real scalar field derived from the Lagrangian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, klein-gordon-equation

The [Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian#Lagrangians_and_Lagrangian_densities_in_field_theory) for a [real scalar field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field_theory) is:

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial_{\nu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2 $$

How can I derive the dynamics of this field from this Lagrangian?

Comment: The question formulation (v2) seems to confuse the action $S=\int \! dt~ L$, the Lagrangian $L=\int \! d^3x~ {\cal L}$, and the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$.

Comment: Actually we write the Lagrangian always for free scalar field, like that but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the action, the action $S$ is the time integral of the lagrangian  $L$, i.e.

$$S=\int L dt $$

The equations of motion for the field $\phi$ is given by the Euler-Lagrange equations for fields (summation over $\mu$ is implicit)

$$\partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\right)-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}=0 $$

which in this case gives the Klein-Gordon equation

$$(\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}+m^2)\phi=0 $$

Comment: thnx. check the editing

Comment: I understand the Euler Lagrangian equation but how can I write for free field?

Comment: For a free scalar field, the equation of motion is the Klein-Gordon equation, that you can derive of the lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$ via the Euler-Lagrange equation